# multiplicative persistence - recursion?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, numbers

I'm working on this:

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num
>   and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of
>   times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single
>   digit.
>
> For example:
>
> persistence(39) == 3 // because 3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4=4
>                         // and 4 has only one digit
>
> persistence(999) == 4 // because 9*9*9 = 729, 7*2*9 = 126,
>                          // 1*2*6 = 12, and finally 1*2 = 2
>
> persistence(4) == 0 // because 4 is already a one-digit number

This is what I tried:

```cs
  public static int Persistence(long n)
        {
            List<long> listofints = new List<long>();

           while (n > 0)
            {
                listofints.Add(n % 10);
                n /= 10;
            }
            listofints.Reverse();
            // list of a splited number

            int[] arr = new int[listofints.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < listofints.Count; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = (int)listofints[i];
            }
            //list to array

            int pro = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                pro *= arr[i];
            }
            // multiply each number
            return pro;
        }
```

I have a problem with understanding recursion - probably there is a place to use it. Can some1 give me advice not a solution, how to deal with that?

Comment: why you wana use recursion here ? it's simple as `int Persistence(long n)
{
 int c = 0;
 while(n / 10 != 0)
 {
  var r = n % 10;
  while((n /= 10) != 0)
   r*= n % 10;
  n = r;
  c++;
 }
 return c;
}`  with recurion `int PersistenceR(long n)
{
 if(n / 10 != 0)
 {
  var r = n % 10;
  while((n /= 10) != 0)
   r*= n % 10;
  return 1 + PersistenceR(r);
 }
 return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me take a stab at explaining when you should consider using a recursive method.

**Example of Factorial:** `Factorial of n` is found by multiplying `1*2*3*4*..*n`.

Suppose you want to find out what the factorial of a number is. For finding the answer, you can write a foreach loop that keeys multiplying a number with the next number and the next number until it reaches 0. Once you reach 0, you are done, you'll return your result.

Instead of using loops, you can use Recursion because the process at "each" step is the same. Multiply the first number with the result of the next, result of the next is found by multiplying that next number with the result of the next and so on.

```
5 * (result of rest)
  4 * (result of rest )
    3 * (result of rest)
      ...
      1 (factorial of 0 is 1).---> Last Statement.
```

In this case, if we are doing recursion, we have a terminator of the sequence, the last statement where we know for a fact that factorial of 0 = 1. So, we can write this like,

```
FactorialOf(5) = return 5 * FactorialOf(4) = 120 (5 * 24)
FactorialOf(4) =    return 4 * FactorialOf(3) = 24 (4 * 6)
FactorialOf(3) =      return 3 * FactorialOf(2) = 6 (3 * 2)
FactorialOf(2) =        return 2 * FactorialOf(1) = 2 (2 * 1)
FactorialOf(1) =          return 1 * FactorialOf(0) = 1 (1 * 1)
FactorialOf(0) = Known -> 1.
```

So, it would make sense to use the same method over and over and once we get to our terminator, we stop and start going back up the tree. Each statement that called the FactorialOf would start returning numbers until it reaches all the way to the top. At the top, we will have our answer.

**Your case of Persistence**

It calls for recursive method as well as you are taking the result and doing the same process on it each time.

```
Persistence(39) (not single)   = return 1 + Persistence(3 * 9 = 27) = 3
Persistence(27) (not single)   =   return 1 + Persistence(2 * 7 = 14) = 2
Persistence(14) (not single)   =     return 1 + Persistence(1 * 4 = 4) = 1
Persistence(4)  (single digit) = Known -> 0  // Terminator.
```

At the end of the day, if you have **same** process performed after each calculation / processing with a termination, you can most likely find a way to use recursion for that process.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got the complete function to process one iteration.  Now all you need to do is add the recursion.  At the end of the function call Persistence again with the result of the first iteration as the parameter.

```
Persistence(pro);
```

This will recursively call your function passing the result of each iteration as the parameter to the next iteration.

Finally, you need to add some code to determine when you should stop the recursion, so you only want to call `Persistence(pro)` if your condition is true.  This way, when your condition becomes false you'll stop the recursion.

```
if (some stop condition is true)
{
    Persistence(pro);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can invoke your multiplication call recursively. 
You will need initial sate (0 multiplications) and keep calling your method until you reach your stop condition. Then you return the last iteration you've got up to as your result and pass it through all the way up:

```cs
int persistence(int input, int count = 0) {} // this is how I would define the method
// and this is how I see the control flowing
var result = persistence(input: 39, count: 0) {
    //write a code that derives 27 out of 39
    //then keep calling persistence() again, incrementing the iteration count with each invocation
    return persistence(input: 27, count: 1) {
        return persistence(input: 14, count: 2) {
            return persistence(input: 4, count: 3) {
                return 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above is obviously not a real code, but I'm hoping that illustrates the point well enough for you to explore it further

Answer (score 0):

Designing a simple recursive solution usually involves two steps:
- Identify the trivial base case to which you can calculate the answer easily.
- Figure out how to turn a complex case to a simpler one, in a way that quickly approaches the base case.

In your problem:
- Any single-digit number has a simple solution, which is persistence = 1.
- Multiplying all digits of a number produces a smaller number, and we know that the persistence of the bigger number is greater than the persistence of the smaller number by exactly one.

That should bring you to your solution. All you need to do is understand the above and write that in C#. There are only a few modifications that you need to make in your existing code. I won't give you a ready solution as that kinda defeats the purpose of the exercise, doesn't it. If you encounter technical problems with codifying your solution into C#, you're welcome to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int PerRec(int n)
{
    string numS = n.ToString();
    
    if(numS.Length == 1)
        return 0;
        
    var number = numS.ToArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Aggregate((a,b) => a*b);
    
    return PerRec(number) + 1;
}
```

For every recursion, you should have a stop condition(a single digit in this case).

- The idea here is taking your input and convert it to string to calculate that length. If it is 1 then you return 0
- Then you need to do your transformation. Take all the digits from the string representation(in this case from the char array, parse all of them, after getting the `IEnumerable<int>`, multiply each digit to calculate the next parameter for your recursion call.
- The final result is the new recursion call + 1 (which represents the previous transformation)

You can do this step in different ways:

```
var number = numS.ToArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Aggregate((a,b) => a*b);
```

1. convert numS into an array of char calling ToArray()
2. iterate over the collection and convert each char into its integer representation and save it into an array or a list
3. iterate over the int list multiplying all the digits to have the next number for your recursion

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
static int Persistence(long n) 
{
    int result = (int)n;
    int count = 0;

    if(result<10)
      return 0;

    while ((result/100) > 0)
    {
        int firstTwoDigits = (int)result/10;
        int firstValue = firstTwoDigits/10;
        int secondValue = firstTwoDigits%10;
        int lastDigits = (int)result % 10;
        result = firstValue * secondValue * lastDigits;
        count++;
        //System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    while(result/10>0)
    {
         int firstValue = result/10;
         int secondValue = result%10;
         result = firstValue*secondValue;
         count++;
         //System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
        return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int Persistence(long n)
{
    if (n < 10) // handle the trivial cases - stop condition
    {
        return 0;
    }

    long pro = 1; // int may not be big enough, use long instead
    while (n > 0) // simplify the problem by one level
    {
        pro *= n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    return 1 + Persistence(pro); // 1 = one level solved, call the same function for the rest
}
```

It is the classic recursion usage. You handle the basic cases, simplify the problem by one level and then use the same function again - that is the recursion.

You can rewrite the recursion into loops if you wish, you always can.